# How do I get a RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller working on 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, lts, realtek, lan

Is there some thing I can search for and install via apt-get or something similar to get my RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

RTL8125 is supported natively by kernel 5.4.
In a little over a month, you will be able to switch to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with this kernel version.

Comment: This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1289417
As of yesterday (June 17, 21), RTL8125 (on my Asrock B560 Steel legend with "Dragon 2.5G LAN controller" --> same as Realtek RTL8125) did not run out of the box with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.