# Unable to download driver for RTL8125 2.5GbE 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek, tethering

I recently build my PC and install a fresh Ubuntu on it. The motherboard is:B550 Aorus Elite (no wifi). Unfortunately the internet does not work over ethernet which lead me to believe that it must not have the necessary drivers for the ethernet device.

```
lshw -C network
```

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
.
.
.

Others have ran into the same problem but they were able to solve it easily since they had access to wifi or tethering. I am actually not sure why my USB tethering does not work. Maybe its because I do not have libmobiledevice as mentioned in this post: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPhone_tethering.

For the ethernet driver, I have tried downloading the driver from their website onto a usb drive and install thru: `sudo ./autorun.sh` but it fails because I need to install build-essential (which I can't do because I dont have internet and I dont know of a easy way to download the .deb files to usb including the dependencies).

Is there any solution to this???

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? You can find `build-essential` here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ . You may need to download other dependencies (you can download everything from another pc or your phone and then copy them to your pc)

Comment: I had the same problem with the RTL8125. Check this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1289417/1048625

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling to get an internet connection, maybe an easier way would be to install a mainline 5.9+ kernel from

[Ubuntu kernel PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

It doesn't require build-essential or other drivers for your device.

Then you can install `build-essential` and revert to an Ubuntu kernel if you like.