# Ethernet connection hangs

Tags: wireless, 22.04, ethernet

I'm getting my wired (i.e. Ethernet) connection hanging on trying to connect. I've tried switching ports (on the router) and using a different cable, but still the same.

ifconfig shows for Ethernet:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:eb:f6:ef:a4:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2779  bytes 250524 (250.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 355  bytes 72171 (72.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo lshw -C enp2s0 shows nothing

lspci -nn shows for Ethernet:
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)

I found a web page:
[how-to-install-realtek-rtl8125-rtl8125b-driver-in-ubuntu-gnu-linux-distro/](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/05/03/how-to-add-realtek-rtl8125-driver-ppa-for-ubuntu-based-systems/)

I followed the instructions and installed realtek-r8125-dkms package OK. On rebooting, I followed the instructed procedure (shown when installing the package) of Enrolling a MOK, creating a password and then entering it when requested on the reboot. But worse in that the Wired option is not shown when trying to connect to internet via router. And my WiFi (using Router) is not working so I'm posting using my Android phone as a Hotspot. Will I have any hair left soon!

I've found another webpage [Essentially installing first the r8168 driver anhttps://askubuntu.com/questions/1287967/cant-get-rtl8125-realtek-driver-working-on-version-20-04/1289417#128941d then the r8168-dkms package & r8125 driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287967/cant-get-rtl8125-realtek-driver-working-on-version-20-04/1289417#1289417)

I've tried both answer 1 & answer 2. Still no improvement after either. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I've been advised on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/2022826/comments/19 to generate & insert r8169, by first downloading GBE Ethernet LINUX driver r8169 for kernel up to 5.19 (i.e.r8169-6.031.00.tar.bz2 from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8110sc-l-s and extracting it to r8169-6.031.00. But I get "Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod." followed by "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8169': Key was rejected by service". How do I correct these problems?

Comment: Just tried a USB wifi device. It also hangs while trying to connect to router.

Comment: Tech Support Realtek told me to disable Secure Boot which I have done. I was then able to compile & install r8125, r8128 & r8128 modules obtained from Realtek website. 'lsmod | grep r81' showed all 3 modules. ifconfig showed the ethernet interface Ok (as enp3s0). However, ethernet still hung on connection. So I rebooted and did 'lsmod | grep 81' only showed r8125! 'modinfo r8169 | grep 8125' showed nothing. Help please!

Comment: My mistake, previous comment should have said r8168 & r8169 as the 2nd & 3rd 'r81' things on the first line.

Also r8169 installs Ok as shown by below even though ethernet connect hangs, but modinfo 'data' disappears on reboot:
$ modinfo r8169 | grep 8125
firmware: rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw
firmware: rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008125sv*sd*bc*sc*i*

The firmware is present as shown by ls -la /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125*

Is there a BIOS parameter or a missing Ubuntu package that would cause this?

Comment: Using 'sudo smartctl -i -a /dev/sda', it shows for '202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain' the number 1. Does this mean that I should change my SSD ASAP? 
PS I've been having lots of problems connecting to my router and even my Phone as a Hotspot.

Comment: Apologies to everyone trying to help. It turns out that the problem is the computer: a 4 month old Asus mini PN50-1. I suddenly remembered that the same thing had happened last August and that the supplier had given me a replacement after I returned the original.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to everyone trying to help. It turns out that the problem is the computer: a 4 month old Asus mini PN50-1. I suddenly remembered that the same thing had happened last August and that the supplier had given me a replacement after I returned the original.